# How to implement the parent activity code when custom child view is touched?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a custom ImageView('CustomImageView') and an Edit-text in a linear layout of an activity 'ImageViewActivity'. The Edit-text is initially set invisible. When the customimageview is touched, and onDraw() is called, I want the visibility of the Edit-text to be set visible. Where should I put the code for this? 
Code for ImageViewActivity:

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_imageview);


    }
}
```

And the code for CustomImageView is:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

Paint paint = new Paint();
float xp = -1, yp = -1;
private Options opt;


public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public void init() {

    opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        xp = event.getX();
        yp = event.getY();

        invalidate();

    } 
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //some code
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (xp >= 0 && yp > 0) {

            canvas.drawCircle(xp, yp, 20, paint);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Pass the custom ImageView an EditText object. Then set it as a field and you can mess with it as much as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement touch listener on your customImageview class and then call the edittext to hide it or show is as you need, for results of touch on custom view you have to define touchlistener on your customview not of activity and you can manage views of parent activity in touchevent of customview  OR other method is implement touch listener on you activity and find the view which is touched if touched view is your custom view then make visible your Edittext. Then you will not need to do anything in onDraw() as regarding the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting the view to visible once you have detected a touch motion on your particular view. Specifically it doesn't matter how the user touches it, since once they touch it you want to show your view (at least that is what you said you wanted).